# Display Notification on Android Device using Firebase or any other way

Tags: android, firebase, phpmyadmin

I have made an forum application in android and used phpmyadmin as my database. But when a question gets a new answer the application should show a notification to all users so how can i do it is there a need to use firebase or by just using a webservice!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to go to the firebase console and create an app. (For this you will need to login into your google account) and follow the steps provided here. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/

Once that is done you will need to add these services to your Manifest.xml file

```
<service
    android:name=".firebase.FirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".firebase.FirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

FirebaseInstanceIdService.class

```
public class FirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseInstanceIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "OnTokenRefresh callback. Token received : " + token);
    }
}
```

FirebaseMessagingService.class

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onMessageReceived.");
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }

    private void showNotification(String message) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Slapr Notification Demo")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }
}
```

Now you can get the tokenId in your activity by doing the following

```
Log.d(TAG, "Recieved token : " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
```

This are the most helpful tutorials that i had found when i started. I hope it helps you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiKCEa5_Cs8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYZVhs6T_W8

Comment: i have used the code you provided but it show **"null"** for the token

Comment: Please go through the tutorial once from the links that i have shared